# Nightly backup and merging backup

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a nightly back up script that makes a backup from one server of any files that have been modified and thensync them across to our back server.

/var/backups/backup-2011-04-02/backuped/ backuped files and folders

The format above is the nightly incremental backup, which copies all the files and folders to a date stamped folder and then another folder underneath.

Thinking of a script which would run after the back up script to merge all the files in the /var/backups/backup-2011-04-02/backuped/ into /var/www/live/documents

So in theory I need to merge a number of different folders from the backup into the live www on the backup server only with the right date

So whats the best way to go about this script?

Comment: @jHackTheRipper Whats the best way to go about do this?

Comment: Perhaps this would be more suited for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

You could run `rsync` on each backup directory to the destination in order of
creation:

```
$ for f in `ls -t /var/backups`; do rsync -aL "/var/backups/$f" /var/www/live/documents/; done
```

Of course you can put this line in a nightly `cron` job.  The only thing to look out for is the line above will choke if the filenames in your backup directory have spaces in them, but it looks like they don't, so you may be ok.

Comment: is they a way just to look at the folder with today's date on it?

Comment: "ls /var/backups/ | grep "\`date +%F\`" will return the folder with today's date, if the date is formatted YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @arronstacy that sounds good to be - so running this a cron job before midnight should rsync all the files and folders in the back up folder to the live files and folders

Comment: @Grimlockz yep that should work.  as with any backup though you should check it to make sure though.  ...also if this answer works for you feel free to click the check next to the vote arrows to accept it, thanks!

Comment: will copying the back up directory to test now... within this folder is a folder called main/backup/ then all the folders so all the rsync's need to copy into this folder then I can test it in a web folder